# Sync with Outlook not working, ULS error: UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized

Tags: tasks, outlook, synchronisation

I am using SP2013 onpremise standard licence. I created a webapplication. I have created a project subsite. In this subsite I would like to make it possible to sync tasks with outlook. I did these steps:

```
You will need to have Exchange 2013 in your environment.
You will also need to install Exchange 2013 Web Services Managed API 2.0
Establish an OAuth trust on the Exchange Server
```

When I click on the button "Sync with Outlook" from the task list I got this error in uls below. Why is it still not working?

```
Timestamp               Process                                     TID     Area                            Category                        EventID Level       Message     Correlation
08/28/2014 12:53:54.24  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (POST:https://aintranet.myCompany.com:443/Project/_layouts/15/ExchangeSyncSettings.aspx?IsDlg=1)   cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.24  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|myCompany\testk, ClaimsCount=72  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.25  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  Site=/  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    UserAgent not available, file operations may not be optimized.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.CreateCobaltStreamContainer(SPFileStreamStore spfs, ILockBytes ilb, Boolean copyOnFirstWrite, Boolean disposeIlb)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileStreamManager.SetInputLockBytes(SPFileInfo& fileInfo, SqlSession session, PrefetchResult prefetchResult)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.CoordinatedStreamBuffer.SPCoordinatedStreamBufferFactory.CreateFromDocumentRowset(Guid databaseId, SqlSession session, SPFileStreamManager spfstm, Object[] metadataRow, SPRowset contentRowset, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.GetDocumentContentRow(Int32 rowOrd, Object ospFileStmMgr, SPDocumentBindRequest& dbreq, SPDocumentBindResults& dbres... cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, ...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion, String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbst...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...rRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetFileAndMetaInfo(String bstrUrl, Byte bPageView, Byte bPageMode, Byte bGetBuildDependencySet, String bstrCurrentFolderUrl, Int32 iRequestVersion, Byte bMainFileRequest, Boolean& pbCanCustomizePages, Boolean& pbCanPersonalizeWebParts, Boolean& pbCanAddDeleteWebParts, Boolean& pbGhostedDocument, Boolean& pbDefaultToPersonal, Boolean& pbIsWebWelcomePage, String& pbstrSiteRoot, Guid& pgSiteId, UInt32& pdwVersion,...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ... String& pbstrTimeLastModified, String& pbstrContent, UInt32& pdwPartCount, Object& pvarMetaData, Object& pvarMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& pbstrRedirectUrl, Boolean& pbObjectIsList, Guid& pgListId, UInt32& pdwItemId, Int64& pllListFlags, Boolean& pbAccessDenied, Guid& pgDocid, Byte& piLevel, UInt64& ppermMask, Object& pvarBuildDependencySet, UInt32& pdwNumBuildDependencies, Object& pvarBuildDependencies, String& pbstrFolderUrl, String& pbstrContentTypeOrder, Guid& pgDocScopeId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetWebPartPageContent(Uri pageUrl, Int32 pageVersion, PageView requestedView, HttpContext context, Boolean forRender, Boolean includeHidden, Boolean mainFileRequest, Boolean fetchDependencyInformation, Boolean& ghostedPage, String& siteRoot, Guid& siteId, Int64& bytes, ...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, Byte& level, Object& buildDependencySetData, UInt32& dependencyCount, Object& buildDependencies, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, String& redirectUrl, Boolean& ObjectIsList, Guid& listId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.FetchWebPartPageInformationForInit(HttpContext context, SPWeb spweb, Boolean mainFileRequest, String path, Boolean impersonate, Boolean& isAppWeb, Boolean& fGhostedPage, Guid& docId, UInt32& docVersion, String& timeLastModified, SPFileLevel& spLevel, String& masterPageUrl, String& customMasterPageUrl, String& webUrl, String& siteUrl, Guid& siteId, Object& buildDependencySetData, SPWebPartCollectionInitialState& initialState, ...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...String& siteRoot, String& redirectUrl, Object& oMultipleMeetingDoclibRootFolders, Boolean& objectIsList, Guid& listId, Int64& bytes)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModuleData.GetWebPartPageData(HttpContext context, String path, Boolean throwIfFileNotFound)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultFromCacheInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithN...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...oAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)     at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()     at System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean in...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...cludeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at ASP._layouts_15_exchangesyncsettings_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRun...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...time.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsP...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ak8dj   High    ...ointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aiv4w   Medium  Spent 0 ms to bind 26737 byte file stream   cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           ahjkm   Medium  Spent 0 ms to send 26737 byte file stream   cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (GetFileAndMetaInfo). Execution Time=21,463691614437    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.27  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (GetWebPartPageContent). Execution Time=21,9115837348043    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.30  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajji6   High    Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry.    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.31  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x32C8)                   0x28A4  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://spweba1:32843/b767caca5f2b4cba8f532b9d2caede3c/WorkManagementService.svc/optimized' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.IWorkManagementServiceApplication' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/IWorkManagementServiceApplication/OptIntoExchangeSync' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:4f84488e-6d61-410d-8b9c-bb7d8d6074f8'    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.33  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://spweba1.myCompany.local:32843/b767caca5f2b4cba8f532b9d2caede3c/WorkManagementService.svc/optimized' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://tempuri.org/IWorkManagementServiceApplication/OptIntoExchangeSync' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:4f84488e-6d61-410d-8b9c-bb7d8d6074f8'   cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.33  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Portal Server        Work Management Service         ahw68   Medium  Creating WmaContextScope with id 1c8e84ca-7ccf-4cbf-95c4-dc5024c7e5ed. There are now 1 scopes in existance for this SPThreadContext cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.33  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk39   Medium  UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging::Begin ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData.ExecuteOnChannel   cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.33  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk35   Medium  MossClientBase_WCFLogging::Begin MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.33  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk36   Medium  MossClientBase_WCFLogging:: MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel -  Executing codeblock on channel   cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.33  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://spweba1:32843/72247c917e05459783a9e6a8656ee382/ProfileDBCacheService.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.IProfileDBCacheService' Action: 'http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetUserData' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:c467a471-9e6d-4690-af46-409703a47e29'    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x16F4)                   0x06BC  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mb    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress: 'http://spweba1.myCompany.local:32843/72247c917e05459783a9e6a8656ee382/ProfileDBCacheService.svc' Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action: 'http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetUserData' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:c467a471-9e6d-4690-af46-409703a47e29'  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x16F4)                   0x06BC  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,0 e5mb cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x16F4)                   0x06BC  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution Time=0,76022231875839    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aipzv   High    Unable to write service call usage entry.   cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteWcfOperation:http://Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles/GetUserData). Execution Time=436,607376077127  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk37   Medium  MossClientBase_WCFLogging:: MossClientBase.ExecuteOnChannel -  Executed codeblock on channel    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (ExecuteOnChannel:GetUserData). Execution Time=441,170805228039 cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Portal Server        User Profiles                   ajk4a   Medium  UserProfileDBCache_WCFLogging::End ProfileDBCacheServiceClient.GetUserData.ExecuteOnChannel cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  UserAccountId=b90089c9-23c9-4112-bea4-63cdd65d4b94  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.77  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Server               Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium  UserAccountName=myCompany\testk cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.78  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Portal Server        Work Management Service         ahw6q   Medium  Successfully loaded the personal site for user b90089c9-23c9-4112-bea4-63cdd65d4b94 at url http://amijnprofiel.myCompany.com/personal/testk and id 929cb20c-d9bc-4e0e-b17c-77ded3e41e27.    cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.78  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope (Reading the User Profile). Execution Time=453,797060799627 cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.78  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8e2s    Medium  Unknown SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070002  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.80  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aix9j   High    SPRequest.GetMetadataForUrl: UserPrincipalName=, AppPrincipalName= ,bstrUrl=http://amijnprofiel.myCompany.com/WmaAggregatorList_Admin ,METADATAFLAGS=59 cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.80  w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002), StackTrace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.GetList(String strUrl)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.DataModel.Internal.ListManager.EnsureList()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.DataModel.ExchangeUserInfoCache.IsUserPresentInList(Guid userProfileId)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.Internal.ExchangeUserManager.OptCurrentUserIntoExchangeSync()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.WorkManagementServiceApplication.<>c__DisplayClass7.<OptIntoExchangeSync>b__6()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.Internal.WmaContextUtils.<>c__DisplayClass1.<ExecuteCodeInsideWmaContext>b__0()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.Inte... cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.80* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  ...rnal.WmaContextUtils.ExecuteCodeInsideWmaContext(Action toRun, WmaContextType allowedContexts)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.WorkManagement.WorkManagementServiceApplication.OptIntoExchangeSync()     at SyncInvokeOptIntoExchangeSync(Object , Object[] , Object[] )     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHa...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.80* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  ...ndler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MultipleReceiveBinder.HandleReceiveRequestComplete(IAsyncResult innerResult, Boolean completedSynchronously)     at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)  ...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.80* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  ...   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.ReceiveItemAndVerifySecurityAsyncResult`2.InnerTryReceiveCompletedCallback(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)     at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.Enqu...  cee6b29c-1dab-1088-0651-40f3239ef497
08/28/2014 12:53:54.80* w3wp.exe (SPWEBA1:0x204C)                   0x2068  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ai1wu   Medium  ...eueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)     at
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a reboot of my frontend server and now it is working:)